# Ruby Module Include

Tags: ruby, module

If I have a class and a module:

```
class Foo
end

module WhackyFoo
  def whacky
    puts 'shits whacky!'
  end
end
```

Why can I do this:

```
include WhackyFoo
Foo.new.whacky
# => shits whacky!
```

Can someone explain or point me to the Ruby docs where this usage is explained?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because when you include module on the top level, it gets included into a special object `main`. Any method defined on `main` (including those included from module) become private instance methods of `Object` (and, therefore, all objects). That's why it works.

If you include a module into a "normal" class (not top level `main`), it behaves as you would expect

```
module WhackyFoo
  def whacky
    puts 'shits whacky!'
  end
end

class Foo
end

class Bar
  include WhackyFoo
end


Bar.new.whacky # >> "shits whacky!"

Foo.new.whacky # ~> -:16:in `<main>': undefined method `whacky' for #<Foo:0x007fa92984d968> (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: So this method is everywhere then.  If I wanted to contain it to Foo, I guess I would have to namespace it.

Comment: @Billy: you'd have to include it in Foo.

Answer (score 1):

The `include` ends up being called on Object, which is what everything in ruby boils down to. Since every class inherits from Object, the method you defined in your module will end up being included in every class.